Linear combination of zero-mean sub-gaussians random variables
Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{1}{2}$ such that $X_i\in[-1,1]$. I know that since the $X_i$ are bounded, they are sub-gaussians at least with $X_i\sim subG(1)$, where $Y\sim subG(\sigma^2)$ if $\mathbb{E}(\exp{(\lambda Y)})\leq\exp{\left(\frac{\sigma^2\lambda^2}{2}\right)}$.
Can we say that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sum_{i = 1}^{k} X_i\sim subG(1)$? Because the $X_i$ are indipendent and so their sum $\sum_{i = 1}^{k}X_i \sim subG(k)$ and by scaling by the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ we get that result.
Question: is this true or I made a mistake? Thank you for your valid help.
Bonus:
in my specific case $X_i = \cos{\theta_i}$ where $\theta_i\sim\mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$ (uniform on $(0,2\pi)$), is it possible to "improve" the variance proxy I gave before?

Notice that by independence and the sub-Gaussianity of the original variables (regarding independence, namely we are using that for independent random variables expectation of product is the product of expectations):
$$
E\left( exp \left( [\lambda/\sqrt{k}]\sum_{i=1}^k X_i \right) \right)= E \left( \prod_{i=1}^k exp \left( [\lambda/\sqrt{k}]  X_i \right) \right)=\prod_{i=1}^k E \left(  exp \left( [\lambda/\sqrt{k}]  X_i \right) \right) \\ 
\le  \prod_{i=1}^k exp(\sigma^2 \lambda^2/2k) = exp(\sigma^2 \lambda^2/2).
$$
So indeed the sum is sub-Gaussian.
